# Android - SQLite avoid DatabaseObjectNotClosedException

Tags: android, sqlite

In my code:

```
private void insertNewRecord(String id) {
    dataHelper.openDB();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("Id", id);
    dataHelper.InsertRescord(TAG_TABLE, values);
    dataHelper.close();
}
```

I have closed my database object . But i getting error

```
android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
```

This code work fine . But in Logcat it show this error. How can I resolve that ?

Comment: You must close all cursor apart from database instance.It looks like you are only closing database object.

Comment: But i don't use cursor in that case

Comment: Check all your methods which you are using for database statements as database can only return data in from of cursor pointing at starting of table for the requested query.

Answer (score 0):

You should close the database "onDestroy"

```
protected void onDestroy(){
    dataHelper.close();
}
```